# Userscript for control tab

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a userscript so that when I hit the 'Q' key on a certain website that it inputs the press down of control and tab, so it switches tabs. I have the following code, but don't know what is wrong

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Multiboxing
// @description  Hit Q to switch tabs
// @match        http://agar.io/*
// @run-at       document-end
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
var overwriting = function(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode === 81) { // KEY_Q
        console.log("Q KEY HIT");
        window.onkeydown({keyCode: 17}); // CTRL
        window.onkeydown({keyCode: 9}); // TAB
        window.onkeyup({keyCode: 17});
        window.onkeyup({keyCode: 9});
    }
};

window.addEventListener('keydown', overwriting);
})();
```

Thanks for any help in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't do it. Browser doesn't give permission to client.

Comment: Is there another way to make it easier?

Comment: No, you cant do it from web document with any tool?

Comment: Actually you can do it with browser plugins (and add-ons). They have permissions to control tabs. And can interract with documents.